# Mongo query for number of items in a sub collection

Tags: mongodb

This seems like it should be very simple but I can't get it to work.  I want to select all documents A where there are one or more B elements in a sub collection.

Like if a Store document had a collection of Employees.  I just want to find Stores with 1 or more Employees in it.

I tried something like:

```
{Store.Employees:{$size:{$ne:0}}}
```

or

```
{Store.Employees:{$size:{$gt:0}}}
```

Just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported. You basically only can get documents in which array size is **equal** to the value. Range searches you can't do.

What people normally do is that they cache array length in a separate field in the same document. Then they index that field and make very efficient queries.

Of course, this requires a little bit more work from you (not forgetting to keep that length field current).

Comment: Well...that sucks.  lol  Wish that was called out somewhere in the documentation, or maybe more clearly.  Spent a LOT of time trying to figure that out.

Comment: I believe it is spelled out somewhere :)